# How to make a JWT with a fully custom payload

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

I have to create a JWT to send it in a REST API service.
The payload of the tocken was defined without "standard" claims.

This is the given example in PHP:

```
$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');
```

Where $payload is a free json string with the payload.

I tried to use Auth0 but

```
JWT.create()
```

doesn't have a fully custom method to set a string or an object as payload.
Is there any way to not use standard JWT claims and set a free payload?

Comment: you could try `com.nimbusds.jwt` library aka Nimbus JOSE + JWT...they have a method for creating a JWT with a String payload: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is where you are using the Auto0 library to create the JWT input object. If this is not possible you will need to use another library that I suggest using Framework spring to solve your problem. Take a look at this link.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework